# Why does this recursive Java method for counting two characters work?

Tags: java, recursion

Trying to learn Java at the moment. I was just solving a few recursion problems, and I came across one that asked me to count the occurrences the substring "hi" in another string. I was looking for recursive ways to do this, and I found a code that basically did what I wanted and I could paraphrase, but I didn't understand how/why it works. I had no issue with the other recursion problems, and I understand the concept of calling a function within its body, but the way this code works puzzles me. Stepping through it in a debugger just confused me.

```
 public int countHi(String str) {
  int n = str.length();
  if(n <= 1) return 0;

  if(str.substring(0, 2).equals("hi"))
    return countHi(str.substring(1)) + 1;

  return countHi(str.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in English what each line of code does one by one? It will help to write that down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically all recursion breaks down to two main insights:

- Base case (or terminating case): What is the simplest problem? Where do you not need to simplify?
- Recursive case: How do you solve the current problem using a simpler problem's solution?

The base case here is when the string is too short - a string of less than two characters obviously can't contain "hi".

The recursive case here is that a string that starts with "hi" has one "hi" more than the rest of the string, but a string that doesn't has exactly as many "hi" when you chop off the start.

The code encodes these two insights.

Comment: oh, that makes a lot more sense! I was kind of confused about why the code repeatedly evaluates on str.substring(1) and how that works out, but upon further inspection that's just slowly breaking the string down into smaller strings of size <= 1 by splitting one character off every time.